# Convert NSObject to NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to convert object of type `NSObject` to `NSNumber` in Objective-C?

In Android I do this:

```
if(value instanceof Integer){
   intValue = (Integer)value;
}
```

But how I can convert value in Objective-C?

**My code:**

```
-(void)changeWithValue:(NSObject*)value{
     if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
          float floatValue = [value floatValue];
 }
```

But it is not working :(

Help me please. Thanks

Comment: Show the code that you have try.

Comment: In Obj-c, "Integer" is not an Object, be careful with that. intValue on an NSNumber for example would return an integer, not an NSNumber

Comment: You do realise that the second method will have no effect as it assigns the value to a local variable which disappears when the method returns.  Is that what you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: @Droppy, it  assigns value from local variable to property late in this method (I removed it and other excess code). My problem was in converting NSObject to NSNumber (you can read title again )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clarification of what your error was the Objective-C-ese solution is to use `id` as the parameter type. The type `id` means "any object type" and the compiler allows you to call any method. So you would have code along the lines of:

```
- (void)changeWithValue:(id)value
{
   if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
   {
      float floatValue = [value floatValue];
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      // handle not an `NSNumber`
   }
}
```

You can make it more general for testing for the method rather than the type by using `respondsToSelector:`:

```
- (void)changeWithValue:(id)value
{
   if([value respondsToSelector:@selector(floatValue)])
   {
      float floatValue = [value floatValue];
      ...
   }
   else
   {
      // handle case where value does not support floatValue
   }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your explain :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this

```
-(void)changeWithValue:(NSObject*)value{
 if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
      NSNumber *num = (NSNumber*)value;
      float floatValue = [num floatValue];
 }
```

Comment: How is this different to the code provided by the OP?  The cast to `NSNumber` will make no difference at all.

Comment: Droppy, I don't understand you

Comment: @Katya This is not your answer; the casting from `NSObject` to `NSNumber` that this answer provides, will not solve your problem.  This code won't compile either.

Comment: @Katya are you able to cast the `NSObject` to `NSNumber`?

Comment: The code won't even compile, so I don't see how it works.  @Nirav: perhaps you'd like to explain why casting to `NSNumber` makes it work please?

Comment: NSNumber *num = (NSNumber*)value; - this works right

Comment: Sigh.  Again; not legal.

Comment: float floatValue = [value floatValue]; - this won't compile

Comment: Yes it will.  That is perfectly legal.

Comment: Droppy, why do you think that this NSNumber *num = (NSNumber*)value; won't compile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118556/discussion-between-katya-and-droppy).

Comment: @Droppy is correct, the added cast does **not** change your object (at runtime), rather it changes the type the compiler treats your object as (at compile time). For example, if you have an object of type `NSNumber` you can lie to the compiler and cast the object reference to an `NSArray` and perform an array operation on it. The compiler will not complain, believing your lie, but at runtime there will be an error as `NSNumber` objects do not respond to `NSArray` operations. In your question you need to more explicit about what "not working" means. Do you get a compile or runtime error, etc.?

Comment: @CRD I had error during compile this (float floatValue = [value floatValue];), because value like NSObject doesn't have methods floatValue. But code which gives Nirav is compiled and works correct (I checked it)

Comment: @Katya - The Objective-C way of doing this is to use the type `id` rather than `NSObject *` – `id` means any object type. I'll show the code in an answer.

Comment: @Katya Perhaps mentioning these compilation errors in your question would have made this whole process much quicker and less hassle.  Please be complete with your questions in future.